# NearSphere Query with paging order by distance

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

In MongoDb I can make queries to get entries near to a point.
As I need paging I use the overload which accepts a sort and a paging parameter.

So my Query looks like this:

```
Filter.NearSphere(x => x.Geolocation, location.Geography.Geolocation.Longitude, location.Geography.Geolocation.Latitude, location.Radius / 6371000), Sort.Ascending(myField), paging)
```

But now I want them sorted by distance. What you I pass to the Sort parameter?